# add more children routes from a module to another

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router

Let's say I have a module named Parent:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/:id',
                component: ChildComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
})
export class ParentModule {
}
```

This module has some child routes for a nice routing experience, but there's an issue with it: I don't know how to add more children routes from another module.

Let's say I want to add a module `ChildDetailsModule` that declares a `ChildDetailsComponent` and wants to bind it to `/:id/details`, then I'm stuck. Because I don't want `ParentModule` to know about this component, since it's provided by another module, I want to be able to unplug it by just removing `ChildDetailsModule` from the imported modules of my `AppModule`.

Is it possible to achieve this? I didn't find a way in the current angular documentation and I definitely have to do this because I need an inner router outlet while I also need to be able to provide additional routes to this inner router outlet using other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You must think in angular routes as a tree, so a parent must exists. However, wath you are looking for is lazy loading.

On the parent module use lazy loading to load a complete module in a route. This way, when user navigates to that route the specified module will provide her own routing and you can add some other child routes or wathever.

Ex:

```
{ 
  path: 'parent/newmodule',
  Loadchildren: 'Newmodulepath#NewModule'
}
```

Comment: would this be in the child module or the parent one?

Comment: @Supamiu you should desing your routes tree, then adapt angular.Your routes tree level should match your components and modules, so you can place this where it suits better